# Changing column name from string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have a table like below:

| Sector | Apr 2022 | May 2022 | Jun 2022 | 1Y Min | 1Y Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 05 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 02 |

The last two column names are constant.
However the column names for the **4/22**, **5/22**, **6/22** columns change depending upon the latest month. These column names are in the `x.strftime('%b %Y')` format.

I want to change the format of the `dataframe[-3]` column name such that it is represented in the **m/d/y** format, i.e change the format of column name only for the latest month.

Wanted solution:

| Sector | Apr 2022 | May 2022 | 6/30/2022 | 1Y Min | 1Y Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 05 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 02 |

Piece of existing code to provide context:

```
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns[:-2]).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y')).to_list() +["1Y Min", "1Y Max"]
```

I want to execute the new piece of code after the above line.

I tried using `df[df[-3]] = pd.to_datetime[df[df[-3]].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y')` but this does not seem to work.
Is there a simple solution?

Comment: `June` does not respect the `%b` format because it should be `Jun` without 'e'.

Comment: And why are Apr 2022 and May 2022 not changed accordingly?

Comment: The latter is my requirement such that the date format of only the last column changes

Comment: The requirement itself makes no sense and strongly suggests an x/y problem

Answer (score 0):

Now you fixed 'June', you can use `pd.to_datetime` and `MonthEnd` to convert the month-year date to month/last_day/year format:

```
# Convert Jun 2022 to 6/30/2022
new_date = (pd.to_datetime(df.columns[-3], format='%b %Y') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)).strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')

df.columns = [*df.columns[:-3], new_date, *df.columns[-2:]]
print(df)

# Output
  Sector  Apr 2022  May 2022  6/30/2022  1Y Min  1Y Max
0      A        10         5         12       5       5
1      B        18        20          9       9       9
2      C         2         9         12       2       2
```